# When to use 'is' and 'has'

Tags: tense

I have a question about where to use is and has. Examples:

> 1. *Tea **is** come* or *Tea **has** come*
> 2. *Lunch **is** ready* or *Lunch **has** ready*
> 3. *He **is** come back* or *He **has** come back*
> 4. *She **is** assigned for work* or *She **has** assigned for work*

Actually these were the sentences that I came across in the last few days, and everybody uses 'is' but I think 'has' is correct, so I'm just confused about how to differentiate 'is' and 'has'. Can you please help clear my confusion?

Comment: Hi, Anu. I asked you specifically not to post the same question on English Language and Learners. Posting the same question on Stack Exchange is not allowed. Please delete your post on English Language and Usage. [When to use 'is' and 'has'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305259/when-to-use-is-and-has).

Comment: *He **is** come* is also right, but is very *archaic*

Comment: Not everybody speaks correct English. Tea is come and He is come back are not correct  as Perfect is formed with have/has + past participle.

Answer (score 1):

*Have* as you used it, it's the **present perfect**, where If you use *be+-ed* you usually form the **Passive form**.

As you can imagine

> is come

doesn't make sense, because that's an active action he does. Instead

> Lunch is ready

is ok, because it's something "Lunch" suffers

If you want more detailed information you can check [this resource](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verb-be).

I would say:

1. Tea has come
2. Lunch is ready
3. He has come back
4. She is assigned for work

Answer (score 0):

When to use present perfect has is right
When to use is a present simple tens
Answer:
Tea has come
Lunch is ready
He is come back
She is assigned for work